# how to find people with same family name?

Tags: sql

You have a table with 4 columns:

Primary key / name / surname / middle name

How to write Sql query to find people who has same family name?

1 /  Ivan / Ivanov / Ivanovich

2 / Petr / Levinsky / Aleksandrovich

3 / Alex / Ivanov / albertovich

Should return Ivan and Alex

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In standard SQL you can simply join the table with itself:

```
select a.name, b.name
from t as a, t as b
where a.surname = b.surname and a.id < b.id
```

where `t` is your table and `id` is the primary key column.

This returns all distinct pairs of first names for every surname that has multiple entries.

You might want to add `surname` to the list of selected columns.

Comment: why is a.id < b.id? I don't get it, can you explain?

Answer (score 9):

If you want to find exactly names then you should firstly find all surnames that appear more than once and the find all names:

```
select name
  from t
  where surname in (select surname from t group by surname having count(surname) > 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to GROUP BY the surname and then use a HAVING clause to find any groups that have > 1.

Untested:

```
SELECT 
  name 
FROM 
  theTable 
WHERE Surname IN (
    SELECT
      Surname
    FROM
      theTable
    GROUP BY
      Surname
    HAVING
      COUNT(Surname) > 1)
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP is asking (return first names).

Comment: @aix - seriously?  I'm presuming that if it's an interview question he'll know a bit about SQL and be able to join to the results from the above query.

Answer (score 0):

As for me easiest way is to group records by surname and then select those with count more than 1.

Answer (score -1):

```
select surname,group_concat(firstname)
from people
group by surname
having count(firstname)> 1;
```